# What are these minifigures

Tags: minifigures, minifigure-identification

Does anyone know what these minifigures are or what sets they are from?

Thanks.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The top figure is

- [sh367 - Justin Hammer](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=sh367#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)
  from [Set # 76077-1 : Iron Man: Detroit Steel Strikes](https://brickset.com/sets/76077-1/Iron-Man-Detroit-Steel-Strikes)

for the second figure, see the answer of shea

Comment: You are incorrect about the second figure – the Harpy figure you link to shares zero parts with the figure in the picture.

Answer (score 3):

The first figure is [Justin Hammer](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=sh367), from the LEGO Marvel Super Heroes line. He only appeared in one set, [76077 Iron Man: Detroit Steel Strikes](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=76077-1).

The second figure is from the LEGO Nexo Knights theme. There are a number of figures that share the same head, torso and legs. It could be:

- a [Shrunken](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=nex072), which appeared in 4 sets and had an additional headpiece
- a [Gargoyle](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=nex089), which appeared in 2 promotional sets and had the headpiece in addition to a neck attachment and wings
- a [Stone Stomper](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=nex102), which included the neck attachment without wings and appeared in [only one set](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=70357-1)
- a [Stone Giant](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=nex124), which appeared in a [single promotional set](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=271722-1) and had a different headpiece and neck attachment to the other figures.